# karate - How to enter the array of email ids in karate-config.js and use it in java file

Tags: karate

There are a list of email ids which i have to send email to. I want to add them to the karate-config.js file and then use it in the java file.

Is that possible?

I tried adding this in the karate-config.js file

```
config.toflatiron= {"test@test.com","test1@test.com"}
```

This is not working

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you need to learn JSON:

```
config.toflatiron = ["test@test.com", "test1@test.com"]
```